# How to do a SELECT SUM(a) FROM b WHERE c=(query with multiple results)

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, how can I correctly write this:

```
SUM(qty) FROM paid WHERE idDoc=(SELECT id FROM doc WHERE this=that)
```

when I am sure that the second query (SELECT id FROM doc WHERE this=that) produces MORE than one result.

I can use any higher level language "on top" to loop through it (I am using it in Delphi and in PHP right now), but I was wondering if it could be done with a single MySQL query (not a procedure, just a query).

Unfortunately I do not know how to better explain it, so I could not find a proper answer Googling about it.

For the time being I will simply use a nested loop around the first query, but doing it internally in MySQL will surely be faster and easier to read.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IN` instead of `=` if I understand correctly

```
SELECT SUM(qty) FROM paid WHERE idDoc IN (SELECT id FROM doc WHERE this=that)
```

Comment: Wow! YES! I didn't know "in" :) I will accept it as soon as I can (still 12 minutes!).

Answer (score 1):

To check condition agains array of values you have to use `IN` clause, like:

```
SELECT SUM(qty)
FROM paid
WHERE idDoc IN (SELECT id FROM doc WHERE this=that)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could just use an INNER JOIN for this:

```
SELECT SUM(qty) 
FROM paid 
INNER JOIN doc ON paid.idDoc = doc.id
WHERE this = that
```

Comment: Better and performant approach; just one caveat that there may be multiple rows for `id` in the `doc` table and that can duplicate the sum.